# php code inside html is being commented out

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My php code is called from the html code in a **wordpress** page. However It is being commented out by the browser.
The code:

```
<?php if (function_exists (gCF)) gCF(); ?>
```

inside a div is being read as following (when I see in firebug or chrome)

```
<!--?php if (function_exists (gCF)) gCF(); ?-->
```

I searched the net and found following similar questions, but sadly there is no apt solution, and nor has anyone mentioned why this is happening. Is it because of doctype???

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763332/inserting-php-into-html-results-in-commented-out-code)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926372/php-in-html-files-not-running-or-being-commented-out)
[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098940/php-code-not-being-rendered-in-browsers)
[Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561993/my-php-code-is-commented-out)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say wordpress page do you mean the tempalte file or in the body of a post?

Comment: Where did you put that code? Within a php file or within a WP post?

Comment: It is in the body of the post

Comment: that's why. imagine how horrible wordpress would be if it executed php in a post body

Comment: oh wait a minute  - yeah wordpress stop execution of php from 3.6.1 - shucks.. how dumb of me to forget.. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me like the code is inside a file that does not have a `.php` extension and therefore the code is being evaluated as `HTML`.

If you want to use `php` in wordpress, make sure it's in a template file (either an existing one or one that you've made).

Comment: .html wouldn't comment it. it would just print it as text

Comment: @KaiQing Actually, in Wordpress that might not be true. Good chances that wordpress itself is doing something with the PHP

Comment: you know, i bet you're right. There may be some pre-processing happening in WP. OP says it was in body of a post though

Comment: I've used WP in many many projects and I can tell you from experience that if PHP escapes the template files ... issues arise ... guarantee you that is what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Wordpress does not support the use of PHP code directly in a post. A simple [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress%20plugin%20use%20php%20in%20posts&aq=f&oq=wordpress%20plugin%20use%20php%20in%20posts&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3j64.3490j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brought up some possible plugins that could allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the file is not being parsed by PHP. Make sure the file extension is PHP or your server is setup to parse that filetype using PHP.